# How to use WordNet similarity perl modules in Python?

Tags: python, semantics, wordnet

I want to use perl modules from [WordNet::Similarity](https://metacpan.org/release/WordNet-Similarity) package to calculate semantic relatedness(Hirst-St Onge, Lexical chains, etc.) between texts. Does anybody have idea about how to use them in python?

Answer (score 0):

`NLTK` is the `Python` interface with `WordNet`.

Check out section 5 on [this page](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) for similarity. You will also have to install the module, the instructions for that [are here](http://www.nltk.org/install.html).

Comment: It doesn't have measures for semantic relatedness. It deals with semantic similarity only.

Comment: Do you mean Levenshtein distance calculations?

Comment: No, I mean Hirst St onge, context vector, extended lesk etc. These are available in WordNet::Similarity(https://metacpan.org/release/WordNet-Similarity) package in Perl Language. I want to import these modules in Python. May be through some wrapper?

Comment: If these are not available you can try to run them from python using subprocess. Something like: `import subprocess` `pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "/somepath/perl_script.pl"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nltk.wordnet.corpus. You should have a synset method available that will return what you need. Basically the wordnet corpus from nltk offers: words, synsets, lemmas, verb frames, similarity etc.
You can check the extensive howto for nltk for code and approach samples.